# calendar formatting using powershell

Tags: powershell

below code will quick select of date from the calendar but not the format which i want the format to be(yyyy,MM,dd):
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

```
$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form 

$form.Text = "Select a Date" 
$form.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @(243,230) 
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$calendar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar
Get-MonthCalendar -Bold $WeekendDays -YBold:yyyy,MM,dd   
$calendar.ShowTodayCircle = $False
$calendar.MaxSelectionCount = 1
$form.Controls.Add($calendar) 

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(38,165)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
$form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(113,165)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$form.CancelButton = $CancelButton
$form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$form.Topmost = $True

$result = $form.ShowDialog() 

if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
$path = "H:\oim\adcbsm007\adcbsm007.txt"
$word = "yyyy,MM,dd"
$replacement = $calendar.SelectionStart
$text = get-content $path
$newText = $text -replace $word,$replacement
$newText > "H:\oim\adcbsm007\karthik.txt"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

using string method

```
$replacement.ToString('yyyy,MM,dd')
```

Comment: Hi Thank you, but i'm getting following error:
Cannot find an overload for "ToString" and the argument count: "1".
At line:7 char:54
+ $newText = $text -replace $word,$replacement.ToString <<<< ("yyyy,MM,dd")
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest